# Laravel IOC not calling the constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ioc-container

I have binding in the service provider

```
$this->app->singleton(
    'App\Models\Subscription\Interfaces\IInvoiceService',
    'App\Models\Subscription\Impl\InvoiceService'
);



class InvoiceService implements  IInvoiceService
{

    protected $repo;


    public function _construct(){

        $this->app = App::getFacadeRoot();

        $this->repo = $this->app['repo'];


    }
    public function Create()
    {
    }
 }
```

In one of the classes in Injected the IInovoice Service.

I am getting the concrete implementation of IInovoice . but the Constructor of the InvoiceService is never getting called

Comment: Could you plz add the code of App\Models\Subscription\Impl\InvoiceService ?

Comment: Updated please check

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
class InvoiceService implements  IInvoiceService
{

    protected $app;
    protected $repo;

    public function _construct($app, $repo) {

        $this->app = $app;
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }

    public function Create() {

    }

 }
```

App\Providers\AppServiceProvider

```
public function register() {

      $this->app->singleton(
          'App\Models\Subscription\Interfaces\IInvoiceService',
          'App\Models\Subscription\Impl\InvoiceService'
      );


      $this->app->when('App\Models\Subscription\Impl\InvoiceService')
        ->needs('$app')
        ->give($this->app->getFacadeRoot());

      $this->app->when('App\Models\Subscription\Impl\InvoiceService')
        ->needs('$repo')
        ->give($this->app['repo']);
}

public function boot(ResponseFactory $response) {

      //uncomment this line to debug InvoiceService Resolving event

      //$this->app->resolving(App\Models\Subscription\Impl\InvoiceService::class, function ($invoiceService, $app)    {
        //dump('resolves InvoiceService', $invoiceService);
      //});
}
```

Then run

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Getting error on the line as  ->give($this->app->getFacadeRoot()) Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::getFacadeRoot()

Comment: please replace $this->app->getFacadeRoot() by App::getFacadeRoot()

Comment: Got error message as  "Call to a member function needs() on null"

Comment: In one of the class i have queried    $this->invoiceService = $this->app['App\Models\Subscription\Interfaces\IInvoiceService'];   $app and $repo are nulls.

Comment: You should inject IInvoiceService in class constructor or in  or, in some cases, "setter" methods 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/container#introduction

Comment: I have two classes in one class i did constructor Injection and in other class i did     $this->invoiceService = $this->app['App\Models\Subscription\Interfaces\IInvoiceService'];  in . both cases values are null