# Laravel Binding Interfaces To Implementations Not calling constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, inversion-of-control

I am trying to bind the interface to implementations as mentioned in the 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/container#binding-interfaces-to-implementations

But the constructor of the concrete class is not getting called ever?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel IOC not calling the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60207552/laravel-ioc-not-calling-the-constructor)

Comment: No that didn't worked